# how to slice a subset of numpy arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Given this array:

```
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

How can I select `[[4,5], [7,8]]`? `a[0::2, 1:;2]` doesn't work

Comment: `print a[1:3, 1:3]` would work fine

Comment: what about select N elements from a given index?

Comment: It depends on the context of index, it a 1D array , 2D array or an ND array.

Comment: Same as the example above. Say select 2 elements from each dimension of an ND array given a N-tuple

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
>>> a[1:3,1:3]
array([[4, 5],
       [7, 8]])
```

The first `1:3` is to select row 1 & 2. The second `1:3` is to select column 1 & 2.